# Virtualization without a OS?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtualization, operating-systems

What is a program like VirtualBox, that can be installed Directly on Hardware, without using any OS?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an level 1 hypervisor.
The most popular is probably VMware ESXI but Microsoft also has an version of Hyper-V called Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016. In case of Oracle they have something called Oracle VM Server. However none of these products are freely available (expect evaluation versions).
None of these products can be used like a normal OS. They mostly come with some very basic text interface to configure network settings and the rest of the configuration is done via an web interface or and remote software.

Comment: Just Installed MacOS X, and it works like a charm!! Thanks so much.